# Is there a way to exit/cancel or set the expiration date for commands that issued by customer.devices.chromeos.issueCommand from google api?

Tags: python, google-api, google-workspace, google-admin-sdk, google-chrome-os

Is there a way to exit/cancel or set the expiration date(default expiration is 6 months) for commands that issued by customer.devices.chromeos.issueCommand method(https://developers.google.com/admin-sdk/directory/reference/rest/v1/customer.devices.chromeos/issueCommand). I am using google workspace Python library(https://github.com/googleworkspace/python-samples) and we are trying to make an inhouse webapp to WIPE_USERS from every chromebooks in a selected OU but encounter with code 400(cannot issue more commands because there are pending commands) after sending around 20 commands. 10 of which is in Pending status. What is the limit for pending commands? Am I going on the wrong road here or missing something or What would be the best logic to go about this?

I also checked GAM and I didn't see anything about cancel or editing expiration date on issueCommand.
https://github.com/taers232c/GAMADV-XTD3/blob/ac765f7db12164132fa99a0b22b723b37fee26f9/src/GamCommands.txt

Thank you!

I was hoping that maybe if I am missing something, I could rewrite the logic of the method in our code otherwise I would love to be able to shorten the expiration time of issueCommand to chromeosdevices so we can send more commands and keep the list of expired commands for other processes.